# undefined method `users_url' for Devise Registration Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just used before_save callback in user model like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :limited_sign_up_inactive
 private 
    def limited_sign_up_inactive
      @allowed_emails = LimitedSignup.pluck(:email)
      unless @allowed_emails.include? self.email
        self.status = false   #getting error  in this line
      end
    end
end
```

Am getting this error

```
NoMethodError at /users
undefined method `users_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0xb4b8c18>
```

while using this line

```
self.status = false
```

I want to change status to false before save based on condition. Help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

My Environment Details:

Ubuntu 12.04 + Rails 3.2.13 + Devise 2.2.4

**Update 1:**

*routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
    root to: "devise/sessions#new"
    get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

**Update 2:**

*Backtrace:*

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `users_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0xb4b8c18>:
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in `polymorphic_url'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:150:in `url_for'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:105:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:74:in `redirect_to'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:25:in `redirect_to'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:60:in `block in redirect_to'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:59:in `redirect_to'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:135:in `redirect_to'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:193:in `navigation_behavior'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:162:in `rescue in to_html'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:160:in `to_html'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:153:in `respond'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:146:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:239:in `respond_with'
  devise (2.2.4) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:27:in `create'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__865168007__process_action__622589868__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__281582452__call__871000944__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
```

**Solution**:

> changed before_save to after_create

and used this line

```
self.update_attribute(:status, false)
```

Comment: problem with routes. you have to show us your routes.rb file

Comment: routes aren't available in your models. This callback is either triggering the use of routes, or an exception is getting raised inside  'self#status=' which is getting rescued by the controller. Can we see the backtrace for the exception

Comment: you can store status in db and save it with `update_attribute(:status, false)`... what is status, by the way?

Comment: @okliv how can i do it? i can't get you (store status in db and save)

Comment: you have User model. right? and `status`, as i can understand, is User instance attribute - is it? then you can change `self.status = false` to `update_attribute(:status, false)` and use this flag in your business logic.. but you have to have a field `status` in `users` table in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `User` model and `status` - is User instance attribute

You can change

`self.status = false`

to

`update_attribute(:status, false)`

Then you can use this flag in your business logic..

(But obvious you have to have a field `status` in users table in db)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue `undefined method 'users_url' for Devise Registration Controller` using **Rails 7** with **Devise**. Apparently, this is a known [issue](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5439).

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, you can fix it by adding the following line:

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

This [answer](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5439#issuecomment-997292547) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by callback: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html . Especially these lines are important:

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last.

And you are using callback which always return false and ruins further actions:

```
def limited_sign_up_inactive
  @allowed_emails = LimitedSignup.pluck(:email)
  unless @allowed_emails.include? self.email
    self.status = false   #getting error  in this line
  end
end
```

It's not devise issue and to avoid it just add "true" to the end of your callback function:

```
def limited_sign_up_inactive
  @allowed_emails = LimitedSignup.pluck(:email)
  unless @allowed_emails.include? self.email
    self.status = false   #getting error  in this line
  end
  true
end
```

Thanks,
Alex.